# Why no shebang in .bashrc/.bash_profile?

Tags: shell, bashrc, profile, shebang

Simple inquiry:  I have just realized that I have never seen a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on top of a `.bashrc` script, which leads me to think the system uses the default shell to source it upon login (`${SHELL}`).  I am pondering over reasons why that is the case, i.e. is it considered a bad habit to use something other than the default shell to run the login script.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are *NOT* scripts. They're configuration file which get sourced every time `bash` is executed in one of 2 ways:

- interactive
- login

The **INVOCATION** section of the bash man page is what's relevent.

> A **login shell** is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`, or
>   one started with the `--login` option.
>
> An **interactive** shell is one started without non-option arguments and
>   without the `-c` option whose standard input and error are both
>   connected to terminals (as determined by `isatty(3))`, or one started
>   with the `-i`  option.   PS1  is  set  and  `$-` includes `i` if `bash` is
>   interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this
>   state.
>
> The  following  paragraphs  describe  how `bash` executes its startup
>   files.  If any of the files exist but cannot be read, bash reports an
>   error.  Tildes are expanded in file names as described below under
>   **Tilde Expansion** in the **EXPANSION**  section.
>
> When bash is invoked as an **interactive** login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file  `/etc/profile`,  if  that  file 
>   exists.   After  reading  that  file,  it  looks  for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`,  and  `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes
>   commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The
>   `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the
>   file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.
>
> When an **interactive** shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if  that file  exists. 
>   This may  be inhibited by using the `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile file`
>   option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead
>   of `~/.bashrc`.

You can control when they get loaded through the command line switches, `--norc` and `--noprofile`. You can also override the location of where they get loaded from using the `--rcfile` switch.

As other's have mentioned you can mimic how these files get loaded through the use of the `source <file>` command or the use of the `. <file>` command.

It's best to think of this functionality as follows:

1. bash starts up with a bare environment
2. bash then opens one of these files (depending on how it was invoked as interactive or login, and then...
3. ...line by line executes each of the commands within the file...
4. when complete gives control to in the form of a prompt, waiting for input

#### Methods for invoking

This topic seems to come up every once in a while, so here's a little cheatsheet of the various ways to invoke `bash` and what they result in. **NOTE:** To help I've added the messages "sourced $HOME/.bashrc" and "sourced $HOME/.bash_profile" to their respective files.

***basic calls***

1. bash -i

   ```
   $ bash -i
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   ```
2. bash -l

   ```
   $ bash -l
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   sourced /home/saml/.bash_profile
   ```
3. bash -il -or- bash -li

   ```
   $ bash -il
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   sourced /home/saml/.bash_profile
   ```
4. bash -c "..cmd.."

   ```
   $ bash -c 'echo hi'
   hi
   ```

   **NOTE:** Notice that the `-c` switch didn't source either file!

***disabling config files from being read***

1. bash --norc

   ```
   $ bash --norc
   bash-4.1$
   ```
2. bash --noprofile

   ```
   $ bash --noprofile
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   ```
3. bash --norc -i

   ```
   $ bash --norc -i
   bash-4.1$
   ```
4. bash --norc -l

   ```
   $ bash --norc -l
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   sourced /home/saml/.bash_profile
   ```
5. bash --noprofile -i

   ```
   $ bash --noprofile -i
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   ```
6. bash --noprofile -l

   ```
   $ bash --noprofile -l
   bash-4.1$
   ```
7. bash --norc -i -or- bash --norc -l

   ```
   $ bash --norc -c 'echo hi'
   hi
   ```

***More esoteric ways to call bash***

1. bash --rcfile $HOME/.bashrc

   ```
   $ bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc 
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   ```
2. bash --norc --rcfile $HOME/.bashrc

   ```
   $ bash --norc -rcfile ~/.bashrc 
   bash-4.1$
   ```

***These failed***

1. bash -i -rcfile ~/.bashrc

   ```
   $ bash -i -rcfile ~/.bashrc 
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   sourced /home/saml/.bash_profile
   bash: /home/saml/.bashrc: restricted: cannot specify `/' in command names
   ```
2. bash -i -rcfile .bashrc

   ```
   $ bash -i -rcfile .bashrc
   sourced /home/saml/.bashrc
   sourced /home/saml/.bash_profile
   bash: .bashrc: command not found
   ```

*There are probably more but you get the point, hopefully....*

#### What else?

Lastly if you're so enthralled with this topic that you'd like to read/explore more on it, I highly suggest taking a look at the Bash Beginners Guide, specifically section: [1.2. Advantages of the Bourne Again SHell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_01_02). The various subsections under that one, *"1.2.2.1. Invocation"* through *"1.2.2.3.3. Interactive shell behavior"* explain the low level differences between the various ways you can invoke `bash`.

Comment: @amphibient - sorry it got a little out of hand, hopefully people will appreciate its value and not punish it with downvotes. With this here we can now reference it in other answer down the road. 8-). I was contemplating making a table to show this but that would've been *crazy* 8-).

Comment: Have actually tested these? I once tried to follow what my bash does in squeeze and it didnt quite behave as the manual suggested

Comment: @Bananguin - every one of those commands was run by me and that's the output that was produced below the commands. The only potential "thing" with my setup might be that my `.bash_profile` includes a line to source the `.bashrc`. But I believe that to be very typical of setups.

Comment: This could be subjective but I would not say that *`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are not scripts*. IMHO they are specific purpose scripts which are implicitly sourced during bash initialization or explicitly when you need to apply their modifications. They do not just configure the bash environment (variables, functions, aliases...) as expected from configuration files. They can do any action as in common scripts. For example they can start various actions like background tasks, write log records, initialize some programs etc. Anyway thank you for the detailed summary!

Comment: This answer is even better than any answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment!

Comment: @JacobTomlinson - thank you for your kind words!

Comment: The command `bash -i -rcfile ~/.bashrc` fails regardless of whether _.bashrc_, _.profile_ or _.bash_profile_ have the shebang or not. It seems the issue is within the argument to `-rcfile` itself - `~/.bashrc` - as it contains a slash. It is expected for the command `bash -i -rcfile .bashrc` to fail, unless _.bashrc_ is in a directory in `PATH`.

Comment: If the claim is that a shebang clashes with `-i -rcfile`, as a counterexample, say you have `$HOME/bin` in your `PATH` and the _bash_ executable as well as _.bashrc_ inside of _$HOME/bin_. Having the shebang `#!./bash` in _$HOME/bin/.bashrc_, executing `cd $HOME/bin; bash -i -rcfile .bashrc` yields no error (Bash 5.2.15).

Answer (score 15):

`.bashrc` scripts are only run by `bash` itself. They're not free-standing, and they're not intended to be `exec`uted by the system. (In fact, they're generally not marked executable, and, as you say, they don't have a shebang line.)

Such scripts are intended to be `source`d, since they generally do things like change environment variables (`$PATH`, for example), which are expected to persist after the script finishes. So it would really be pointless to try to execute one in a subshell.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other replies, note that if you want it, nothing forbids you to put a shebang at the beginning of these configuration files.

That wouldn't hurt shell sourcing them as the shebang will be processed just like a regular comment, i.e. ignored.

That might help editors that use syntax highlighting to figure out what programming language is used in the file.

Note that some editors like `vim` provide alternative ways like modelines for the latter though. i.e. you can always put mode lines at the end of the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` like so:

```
...
<code in ~/.bashrc>
...
# vim: ft=sh :
```

Comment: The accepted answer from @slm above is great, but this is what I was looking for, with regard to adding a shebang to the start of my `.bash_profile` on a recommendation from ShellCheck.

Comment: Shellcheck has a `shell` directive, so you can put, for example, `# shellcheck shell=bash` at the start of a file for Shellcheck to treat the file as a Bash script. Having `# vim: set ft=bash:` is useful to get rid of the annoying syntax highlighting for `$()` when having a `#!/bin/sh` shebang (Vim treats `$()` as non-POSIX for some reason).

Answer (score 2):

I read this anywhere don't know where exactly but it's true

> The Bash manual is a bit confusing in this area, but Bash does not
>   eXecute ~/.bash_profile like a shell script. It does read the file and
>   then executes the commands within it (You can do something similar by
>   running source ~/.bash_profile).