# What is the purpose of (and possibly the convention of using) multiple locations for user configuration in fish shell

Tags: configuration, fish

I have recently moved to *fish* from *bash*. I'm immediately in love with the out-of-the-box functionality, but I'm a little bit at a loss when it comes to configuring the shell.

I've read through the [documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization), particularly the [section about initialization](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#), and it states:

> On startup, Fish evaluates a number of configuration files...
>
> - Configuration snippets in files ending in .fish, in the directories:
>
>   - `$__fish_config_dir/conf.d` (by default, `~/.config/fish/conf.d/`)
>   - ...
> - User initialization, usually in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` ...

So far, this is clear to understand. Coming from bash, I took my `.bash_globals` and `.bash_aliases` files, rewrote them a little bit according to fish's syntax, placed them into the `~/.config/fish/conf.d/` and they are loaded as expected.

However, when I looked over the contents of the `config.fish` file, I couldn't figure out anything that would need to be put there. To my understanding, fish is designed to work already out of the box, so the usual bash config like setting `HISTCONTROL` isn't necessary. Nor are the `conf.d/` files called from some main script (like the `.bash_aliases`, etc., would be in `.bashrc`) - they're loaded automatically.

Is there some particular use case where `config.fish` is preferred - or even required - over `conf.d/` files? So far, I would say individual files are cleaner to read, maintain and move between hosts. Is there some convention that's recommended to follow? Was there a specific motivation behind allowing so many levels of config, aside from giving users more freedom?

Comment: Note that neither `.bash_globals` nor `.bash_aliases` are standard bash features. I know Ubuntu creates this `.bash_aliases` file and sources it from `.bashrc`, so maybe some other Linux flavors also do it, but it has nothing to do with `bash`. I don't even know what `.bash_globals` is, probably something specific to whatever system you are using. Also, there is no need to set `HISTCONTROL` or anything else in `bash`. If you are happy with the defaults, you can leave them. It works perfectly well out of the box.

Comment: @terdon I see, thank you for the clarification! I'm most certainly overthinking this - I managed to get everything working so far - though I prefer knowing if there are any potential caveats, like (this is a made-up example) the non-interactive shell behaving differently, etc.

Comment: No caveats along those lines that I'm aware of - With either `config.fish` or `conf.d/` files, you have the option of wrapping them in an `if status is-interactive` or `if status is-login` if there's something you would prefer to run only in those types of shells.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Might I ask for one extra detail? Is shebang required, or recommended in `config.fish` or the `conf.d/` files?

Comment: I can't think of any use-case where a shebang would be needed in any of those files, for the same [reason that it's not needed in bash startup scripts, err, configuration files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88733/432493).  Note that `fish` does behave differently in at least one way from `bash` as described in that answer -- It *does* execute the startup files when executed with `-c command`.  That's why I do like to wrap my startup files in `if status is-interactive` or `if status is-login` where appropriate.  But it doesn't change the (lack of) need for a shebang in those files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as purpose, I'd say there are several good reasons to support both.

First, and probably most importantly, as @Zanchey points out in the comments, `conf.d` support came about in release 2.3.0, so getting rid of `config.fish` at that point would have been a breaking change.

Second, as you said, freedom for the users to choose the way they would like to handle startup behavior.

Next, it's also somewhat "path of least resistance".  I definitely share your preference for the modularity of `conf.d/` files, and I love not having a `config.fish` myself. But some (perhaps even most) users who are moving over to `fish` for the first time default to the familiarity of a single `.bash_profile`-like place to put their config.  I can imagine that the paradigm shift of *not* having a single-file config might be off-putting to some.  In other words, `config.fish` helps provide a smooth migration for new users.

Further, `config.fish` is easier to explain to a new user, since it maps to something they already know in their previous shell.  Even the `fish` [FAQ](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-run-a-command-every-login-what-s-fish-s-equivalent-to-bashrc-or-profile) defaults to telling users that `config.fish` is the equivalent of their previous startup scripts.  Although I do wish they'd go on to explain the `conf.d/` alternative as well there.

And `config.fish` does have one other small advantage, in that the execution order is more explicit (i.e. it's executed start to end).  `conf.d/` files are read just like any other `conf.d/`, in alphabetical order (or glob-result order, most likely).  In my experience, this means that you have to resort to `00_dependency.fish` type of naming to ensure that one file is run before others.  That said, it should rare that anyone would have to resort to that.

As for "convention", well, I know many distributions set up their configuration files (e.g. the Apache2 `httpd.conf`) with a default "single-file" that goes on to process a `conf.d/` structure.  In `fish`'s case, they just did away with the boilerplate `for conffile in ~/.config/fish/conf.d/*.fish; source $conffile; end` that would otherwise be required in `config.fish`.

Comment: Finally, `config.fish` has been available since forever, while `conf.d` was only added in 2.3.0 (released in 2016).

Comment: Thank you! I had been wondering about that when I wrote up the answer (having only been using fish for a couple of years now).  I scanned the source and release notes.  Thought I saw something about conf.d in the commit history that went back to 2012, but I was apparently wrong on that count.  Now that you point me to the release, I see the *"Add new directories for vendor functions and configuration snippets (#2498)"*  Edited that into the answer.

Comment: is there an easier way to source all files from a folder? I want to have a folder containing only secrets. So I can commit my ~/.config/fish to GitHub without secrets.

Comment: @BenKeil - this is better asked as a separate question, but I recommend something like `source ~/.private/fish/config.fish` or `for conf in ~/.private/fish/conf.d/*.fish; source $conf; end`.