# How can root get access to SSH_TTY

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh, motd

I *think* that `SSH_TTY` is an environment variable set by `ssh` that holds the device node of the current virtual terminal; e.g. `/dev/pts/0`, `/dev/pts/1` , etc.

I know that when I'm logged in to an SSH server, I can see the device node assigned to each session by simply entering `echo $SSH_TTY`. And I can see *all* device nodes in use (at least under my username) by entering `w` or `who` from the terminal. I can use the value of `$SSH_TTY` in a script in `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash-profile`) to (e.g.) make decisions about which directory to open for each session. IOW, `SSH_TTY` has an assigned value by the time my login has progressed to reading `~/.profile`.

I'd also like to communicate the value of `SSH_TTY` to the user in the MOTD, but am currently unable to do this. I *think* this is because `root` runs all the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` at login, and `root` has no `SSH_TTY`. And so I've looked for a *work-around*.

The only one I've found is this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh
su pi -c echo "Greetings, I see you rode in on $SSH_TTY"
```

But this fails silently.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try the output of `who -m`.  The 2nd field is usually the stdin device without the leading `/dev/`.

Comment: Usually `/etc/update-motd.d` is not run on every login, but periodically by `cron`, and the user gets shown a cached version.

Comment: @SottoVoce: I guess that you didn't try this, but here's what I get: `$ who -m` => `pi       pts/1`. But if I put this in my script & try it as `root` (or let `/etc/update-motd.d` run after login), I get: `pi       pts/3`. In other words, an incorrect device.

Comment: @Panki: I'm *pretty sure* that's not the case; i.e. `/etc/update-motd.d` is run at login. Try it yourself: add a script that outputs a date/time, and then login.

Comment: The question from the opening sentence can be easily answered with [`man ssh`](https://www.mankier.com/1/ssh#Environment): _This is set to the name of the tty (path to the device) associated with the current shell or command. If the current session has no tty, this variable is not set._

Comment: If the intention is to only display the value of `SSH_TTY` on SSH login, then just adding something like `printf "SSH_TTY=%s\n" "$SSH_TTY"` to _$HOME/.profile_ on the SSH server should do the trick. I just tested it on OpenBSD.

Comment: @Vilinkameni: The question says, *"I'd also like to communicate the value of SSH_TTY to the user in the MOTD"*.

Comment: @Seamus This [update-motd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man5/update-motd.5.html) seems to be Ubuntu-specific, so I suggest adding the appropriate tag. About the question, from the file [_session.c_](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/tree/session.c#n1576), we can see that the `do_setup_env` function, which sets `SSH_TTY` inside of the SSH server, is called _after_ the session is already set up, so there is no way for the update-motd framework to access it.

Comment: @Vilinkameni: It is **not** Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: @Seamus Quote [update-motd(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man5/update-motd.5.html): _Ubuntu introduced the update-motd framework,_...

Comment: update-motd(5) certainly _originated_ on Ubuntu (no reason not to believe the official Ubuntu manpage stating that claim), although admittedly that doesn't mean it couldn't have been _adopted_ by some other distributions. The update-motd "framework" doesn't exist in at least two Unix-like systems I can immediately check: Alpine Linux and OpenBSD.

Comment: Related to my previous comment: https://repology.org/project/update-motd/versions - so it seems there is an AUR package, though clearly having an Ubuntu Launchpad URL as upstream. The other two distributions having the package (according to repology.org) are Amazon Linux and Trisquel.

Answer (score 0):

From the file [session.c](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/tree/session.c#n1576), we can see that the `do_setup_env` function, which sets `SSH_TTY` inside of the SSH server, is called after the session is already set up, so there is no way for Ubuntu's¹ [update-motd(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man5/update-motd.5.html) framework to access it and add it to */etc/motd*.

Since the main part of the intention from the question is presumably to "communicate the value of `SSH_TTY` to the user", simply outputting the value of that environment variable from the user's *$HOME/.profile* on the server should fulfil that request. If it is needed to save that value for whatever reason, the output can be logged to a file, eg:

```
# Contents of $HOME/.profile ...

printf "SSH_TTY=%s\n" "$SSH_TTY" | tee "$HOME"/.ssh_tty
```

---

¹ According to the update-motd(5) manual page itself,

> Ubuntu introduced the update-motd framework

this can be confirmed by examining package repositories of Trisquel and Amazon Linux, the only other distributions having the package besides the (not officially supported) Arch **User** Repository (source: [repology.org](https://repology.org/project/update-motd/versions)).

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not a native English speaker, but I looked up "fulfill" vs "fulfil" and "fulfil" seems to be British English spelling, while I am using the American English spelling of "fulfill".

Comment: @Kusalananda Also, I'm curious about why you removed the shebang. The code snippet should represent the contents of _$HOME/.profile_, and even if that file might not be intended to be executed directly, it helps, for example, the commands like file(1) and xdg-mime(1) to determine the type of file.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the spelling of that word only because I thought it was misspelt, and I'm generally using British English.  As for the `#!`-line, it is used to indicate what interpreter the kernel should invoke to run the file.  Since it's _sourced_, it should never be considered as a script in its own right. Besides, it may give the impression that it's 1) only for `/bin/sh`, and 2) it can or should or must be run as a script.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88728/why-no-shebang-in-bashrc-bash-profile

Comment: If _/bin/sh_ is a symbolic link to a shell, most shells interpret being executed in such a manner as "POSIX mode". The commands accepted by _/bin/sh_ should work in most shells. I'm using _/bin/sh_ in my scripts to achieve better portability, and it is my belief that a human reader should get that impression when looking at the code using that shebang. The argument about `-rcfile` is kind of a moot point, because it uses a [nonstandard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) feature of Bash, which should be used for _.bashrc_ and not _.profile_ in the first place.

Comment: Bash uses `~/.profile` if `~/.bash_profile` is not available. I also thik it's just a strange thing to include the `#!` line in this specific answer, as the answer has nothing to do with the `#!` line.